# Dynamically determined height

Tags: css

I am trying to give a div a dynamic height depending on screen size. In the div I have a calendar that has multiple lines of content, that can be shown or not (user's choice), e.i. the calendar's height is not fixed. With that in mind I have div's height set to `auto`. Which works fine (the height is set according to number of lines in calendar).

The problem arises when I make the browser's height smaller than the amount of height that calendar needs. It becomes a scroll which is not a problem, the position of the scroll is. The scroll is placed on the entire div not on the calendar in the div. The scroll is correct, if the div does not have it's height set, but it does not dynamically shrink to fit only the content (it stays the same height no mater if there is content of not) and I am trying to avoid that.

I suppose the solution is to say that if the div has enough space to use `auto` and if not it should have the height of it's parent. The `min` does not take parameters such as auto. I am a bit lost as to how to write code correctly to achieve this preferably using only CSS.

EDIT:

html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class = "calendar">
       <div class = "content">
       <\div>
    <\div>
<\body>
<\html>
```

CSS:

```
body {height: 100vh; overflow: hidden}
. calendar {overflow-y: auto;}
. content {height: auto;} \\the problem
```

The height of calendar in JS is set to `"parent"`

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you with this when you haven't shown us any of your existing HTML, CSS or JS

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: The code added above.

Comment: _“The `min` does not take parameters such as auto.”_ - no, but it would take 100% - but that would require that the parent element also has an explicit height set, which you currently don’t have.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by your answer I am sure you want to make the content responsive. So there is an easy trick or you can say a cheat sheet for your requirement.

**Step 1**: Include Bootstrap 4 CDN scripts

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
    </script>
```

**Step 2**: In your HTML, write a classname as 'form-group' to adjust your calendar's height content as per the screen size.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class = "calendar">
       <div class = "content">
       <\div>
    <\div>
</div>
```

**Step 3:** Run your project and see how your width of the container adjusts according to the browser when you drag or make it small.

```
Hope this helps.
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there maybe a solution using Sass?

Comment: Sass can be used if you are actually applying CSS to parent container and/or child container. As you can see in above answer, there is literally no CSS. So there is actually no need of Sass. Hence, you have clean code. :) If you like the answer and if it works, please mark it as answer.